# Como ler dados de PDF no R?

Tags: r, pdf

Tenho inúmeros arquivos PDF contendo relatórios de poços d’água da **CPRM**, como este:

**http://siagasweb.cprm.gov.br/layout/pdf/exportar_pdf.php?ponto=4300000556**

Dentro destes arquivos encontram-se informações sobre a litologia do solo de cada poço, como pode ser observado na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela da litologia está na segunda folha do arquivo e varia conforme as características do poço. Preciso agrupar tais informações destes arquivos em um único local, pensei em um *dataframe*.

Como posso ler os arquivos PDF e depois agrupar estas informações utilizando o R?

Comment: Arquivos PDF são complicados. Se você usar o pdftotext, por exemplo, as informações ficam bagunçadas. Por que não lê os arquivos direto da web, sem exportar? Parece ser mais fácil extrair da aba "Geológicos" do que do PDF, no endereço: http://siagasweb.cprm.gov.br/layout/detalhe.php?ponto=4300000556#tabs-3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vou te dar uma resposta incompleta porque estou sem tempo, mas acho já pode ajudar.

Alguém pode depois editar acrescentando o último passo.

Você pode usar o pacote `extractr`. Leia a instrução de instalação aqui:
https://github.com/sckott/extractr.

Esse pacote usa uma série de API's disponíveis na internet para converter um PDF em texto.

Para o seu pdf, fiz assim:

1) Salvei no meu desktop e chamei a função:

```
library(extractr)
xpdf <- extract("Desktop/doc.pdf", "xpdf")
```

2) Separei a parte do texto em que estão os dados que você precisa usando substrings.

```
> lito <- str_locate(xpdf$data, "Litológicos") #procura o fim de litologicos
> hidro <- str_locate(xpdf$data, "Hidrogeológicos") # procura o início de hidrogeologicos
> dados <- str_sub(xpdf$data, start = lito[2] + 4, end = hidro[1]- 5)
> dados
[1] "De (m):, , Até (m):, , Litologia:, , Descrição Litológica:, , 0, , 3, , Arenito fino, , SOLO E ARENITO FINO A MUITO FINO, QUARTZOSO, ESBRANQUICADO, MUITO POUCO ARGILOSO, , 3, , 13, , Arenito fino, , ARENITO FINO A MUITO FINO, AVERMELHADO, MODERADAMENTE ARGILOSO, , 13, , 21, , Arenito argiloso, , ARENITO FINO A MUITO FINO, ESBRANQUICADO, MUITO POUCO ARGILOSO, CONCENTRACOES LOCALIZADAS, , 21, , 42, , Arenito fino, , ARENITO FINO A MUITO FINO, ESBRANQUICADO A ROSADO, MODERADAMENTE ARGILOSO, , 42, , 55, , Arenito fino, , ARENITO FINO A MUITO FINO, ESBRANQUICADO A ROSADO, POUCO ARGILOSO, , 55, , 60, , Arenito fino, , ARENITO FINO A MUITO FINO, COM TONS AVERMELHADOS, FORTEMENTE ARGILOSO, , 60, , 63, , Arenito fino, , ARENITO FINO A MUITO FINO, TONALIDADE ROSEA, MODERADAMENTE ARGILOSO, , 63, , 70, , Arenito fino, , ARENITO FINO A MUITO FINO, TONALIDADE ROSEA, MODERADAMENTE ARGILOSO, , 70, , 76, , Arenito fino, , ARENITO FINO A MUITO FINO, TONALIDADE ROSEA, POUCO ARGILOSO, , 76, , 87, , Arenito fino, , ARENITO FINO A MUITO FINO, TONALIDADE ROSEA, MODERADAMENTE ARGILOSO, , 87, , 102, , Arenito fino, , ARENITO FINO A MUITO FINO, TONALIDADE ROSEA, POUCO ARGILOSO"
```

Agora, o que você precisa tentar fazer é converter essa string em um data.frame.

Enfim, essa é uma maneira... Mas como o Molx disse pdfs são sempre complicados, acho que o melhor caminho seria tentar extrair da página da internet mesmo.

Comment: Esse `extractr` parece funcionar relativamente bem. Dá pra transformar em um dataframe com o seguinte código: `df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(x = dados, split = ", , ")), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
colnames(df) <- df[1,];
df <- df[-1,];
df[,1] <- as.numeric(df[,1]);
df[,2] <- as.numeric(df[,2])`
Mas eu ainda acho um pouco "arriscado", o padrão `", , "` funcionou bem mas pode ser que dê errado para outro pdf, bagunçando tudo.