# Leitura de pdf via R

Tags: r, pdf, dataframe

Preciso converter os dados do PDF abaixo em um data frame:
http://www2.alerj.rj.gov.br/leideacesso/verArquivo.asp?idArquivo=635

Fazendo uma pesquisa por encontrei o [Como Ler Dados de PDF no R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88413/como-ler-dados-de-pdf-no-r). Tive alguns problemas para instalar o pacote, mas consegui no final das contas fazê-lo funcionar no RStudio. Mas o resultado não foi satisfatório, pois nas colunas com 3 ou mais linhas em branco ele já pula para outra coluna.

Comment: Você pode adicionar o código que usou para tentar extrair as informações?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando o pacote [`tabulizer`](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer), eu extraí as informações só da primeira página para testar:

```
library(tabulizer)
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
url <- 'http://www2.alerj.rj.gov.br/leideacesso/spic/arquivo/folha-de-pagamento-2018-01.pdf'
d <- extract_tables(url, encoding = "UTF-8", pages = 1)
```

Depois transformei a lista em data frame, transformei em `chr`, nomeei as variáveis e retirei a primeira linha (que na verdade é o nome das variáveis)

```
d <- as.data.frame(d)
d <- d %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(as.character(.)))
names(d) <- d[1,]
d <- d[-1,]
```

Depois é necessário realizar uma limpeza nas informações, como o separador de milhar, o separador de decimal que no pdf está como `,` e transformar essas informações em `numeric`

```
d <- d %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(gsub("-", NA, .)))
d <- d %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(VENCIMENTO:`TOTAL LÍQUIDO`), funs(gsub("\\.", "", .))) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(VENCIMENTO:`TOTAL LÍQUIDO`), funs(as.numeric(gsub(",", "\\.", .))))
```

Se você retirar a opção `pages` da função `extract_tables` ele vai puxar todas as páginas do pdf e colocar dentro de uma única lista. Para a junção em uma única tabela, acho que `do.call(rbind, d)` vai resolver.

Comment: Ao tentar instalar o `tabulizer` tive o seguinte erro:


`> devtools::install_github("leeper/tabulizer")
Installation failed: Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection refused`

Estou numa rede corporativa com firewall e proxy e não tenho a certeza que conseguiria pedir uma exceção. O que me incomoda é que mesmo fazendo o dwonload do .zip e pedindo para instalar o RStudio não me dá nenhuma mensagem de erro (ou sucesso) na instalação e eu não consigo carregar o pacote, afirma que ele não existe.

Comment: @FlavioSilva um tempo atrás eu tive um problema parecido e pesquisando na internet, cheguei à essa [solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793863/devtoolsinstall-github-ignore-ssl-cert-verification-failure). `set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )` Veja se a mesma funciona para você.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente a solução. Desisti de tentar fazer no trabalho e fiz no meu PC de casa!