# Como transformar tabela de pdf em um data frame com o R?

Tags: r, pdf

Estou querendo transformar uma tabela de um documento .pdf em um data frame no R. Qual seria a maneira adequada para se fazer isso?
A tabela esta ordenada por nome do autor e possui 5 colunas (Título, Número de chamada, Série, Editora e Entidades).
Notem que o nome do autor aparece dentro da coluna Titulo.
Segue a imagem de uma página do arquivo...[image: tabela por autor.pdf]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Brasil! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível. Uma dica: é impossível pra gente tentar te ajudar com uma imagem do pdf em questão. Tente compartilhar o arquivo conosco.

Comment: Ou ainda de [Como ler dados de PDF no R?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88413/como-ler-dados-de-pdf-no-r)